# problem adding flutter_dialogflow dependency into flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to make a chatbot using dialogflow in flutter and currently facing this error trying to add dialogflow dependency and i do not know how to solve it. can anyone help?

The current Dart SDK version is 2.16.2.
Because firebase_auth >=3.3.15 depends on firebase_auth_web ^3.3.13 and no versions of firebase_auth_web match >3.3.13 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.3.15 requires firebase_auth_web 3.3.13.
(1) So, because firebase_auth_web 3.3.13 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0 and http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.3.15 is incompatible with http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0. Because flutter_dialogflow <0.1.0 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0 and flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.0 <0.1.3 depends on http ^0.11.3+16, flutter_dialogflow <0.1.3 requires http ^0.11.3+16.
And because http >=0.2.8+2 <0.11.3+17 requires SDK version <2.0.0 and flutter_dialogflow >=0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.0+2, every version of flutter_dialogflow requires http ^0.11.3+17 or ^0.12.0+2.
And because firebase_auth >=3.3.15 is incompatible with http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 (1), firebase_auth >=3.3.15 is incompatible with flutter_dialogflow.
So, because knowyoursim_app depends on both firebase_auth ^3.3.15 and flutter_dialogflow any, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in knowyoursim_app...
pub get failed (1;     So, because knowyoursim_app depends on both firebase_auth ^3.3.15 and flutter_dialogflow any, version solving failed.)

this is my dependencies

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_core: ^1.15.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.15
test: ^1.19.5
bloc: ^8.0.3
flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
equatable: ^2.0.3
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
search_app_bar_page: ^2.1.2
#dialog_flowtter: ^0.3.3
bubble:
intl:
flutter_dialogflow:

Answer (score 0):

Hi try those steps and it might work :

1 - type '$flutter clean' on console.
2 - then run '$flutter pub get' .
3 - then '$flutter pub outdated' .
4 - after that run '$flutter pub upgrade --major-versions' that should force it to upgrade your packages .

Comment: hi thank you for the reply, have tried this but still getting the same error..      
I can't proceed the second step flutter pub get as it still show the same error as on top

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing the latest dialogflow dependencies..
dialogflow_flutter: ^1.0.0

or try using  this sdk: ">=2.17.0-182.2.beta <3.0.0".